# React Redux Combine Reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

In Redux, if I am using say a data structure as follows:

```
{ 
    products: [ 
                {id:1, name:'tv', description:'A color Sony TV', cost:1000}, 
                {id:2, name:'remote control', description:'A black compact Remote Control', cost: 999}
    ],
    shoppingCart: [],
    checkoutCart: []
}
```

And I use the Redux `combineReducers`

```
combineReducers({products, shoppingCart, checkoutCart})
```

If I wanted to copy the `shopping Cart` data into the `checkoutCart` say on a click event, where would I do so / or should I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `combineReducers` you're assuming the reducers are indepedent and they cannot see each other's state. Each reducer will only receive a "slice" of the state.

In order to achieve what you want, I would consider joining the `shoppingCart` and `checkoutCart` reducers / state into a single one and using `switch (action.type)` to know what to do.

Now you can simply create an action on your new reducer that returns something like

> { checkoutCart: clone(state.shoppingCart) }

Comment: so I would have to move the `shoppingCart` and `checkoutCart` down a level (in the state data) so that that slice could be accessed by the appropriate reducer.

Comment: @avrono. That's a possibility. As others have said, you also have the option to pass `shoppingCart` as the payload of an action.

Comment: @avrono I think it's a matter of what you think suits best

Comment: I am using `containers` with `connect` - but struggling to pass the `shoppingCart` to the click handler in the container ... do you have an example ?

Comment: @avrono If you want to pass the shoppingCart as a payload, you have to do that in the component. Get the data in the component and pass it to the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone your `shoppingCart` to the `checkoutCart`. You could in your `onClick` function pass `this.props.shoppingCart` as a parameter to your action call.

```
onClick(e) {
    this.props.checkOutActions.checkOut(this.props.shoppingCart);
}
```